# Filter an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I have a hash like below.  How can I get the "name" of the "tag" where the tag_type is "LocationTag"? In this case, the returned value would be 'singapore'.

Is the best method just to do:

```
location = nil
tags.each do |t|
  if t["tag_type"] == "LocationTag" 
    location = t.name
  end
end
```

or does ruby have a better method for filtering hashes?

```
   {
      tags: [
        {
          "id": 81410,
          "tag_type": "SkillTag",
          "name": "angular.js",
          "display_name": "Angular.JS",
          "angellist_url": "https:\/\/angel.co\/angular-js"
        },
        {
          "id": 84038,
          "tag_type": "SkillTag",
          "name": "bootstrap",
          "display_name": "Bootstrap",
          "angellist_url": "https:\/\/angel.co\/bootstrap"
        },
        {
          "id": 1682,
          "tag_type": "LocationTag",
          "name": "singapore",
          "display_name": "Singapore",
          "angellist_url": "https:\/\/angel.co\/singapore"
        },
        {
          "id": 14726,
          "tag_type": "RoleTag",
          "name": "developer",
          "display_name": "Developer",
          "angellist_url": "https:\/\/angel.co\/developer"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the first hit:

```
tags.detect{|tag| tag['tag_type'] == 'LocationTag'}['name']
```

This will give you all hits as an array

```
tags.select{|tag| tag['tag_type'] == 'LocationTag'}.map{|t| t['name']}
```

Check out the docs for [Ruby#Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) for more details.

[Ruby#Enumerable:detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect)

[Ruby#Enumerable:select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

(Thanks @PaulRichter for the comment... it's a nice clarifying addition to the post)

Comment: [Direct link to `detect` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect)

Comment: @PaulRichter: `find` is another alias.

Comment: I try to avoid `find` only because in Rails, on AR objects, `find` is really different than `detect`.  So to keep things clear (for me), I try to use `find` when it's an `AR#find` and `detect` when it's an `Enumerable`.  Just a matter of preference.

Comment: It does appear that `detect` and `find` are the same thing. Anyone know the reason for the different names (assuming there is no practical difference, other than the preferential reason mr rogers mentioned)?

Comment: @PaulRichter: Best I'm aware the aliases are nothing more than a reflection of Matz's views on what is natural: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Philosophy

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to stop the iteration once you've found a result:

```
location = tags.find { |t| t["name"] if t["tag_type"] == "LocationTag" }
```

Mind the errors that got fixed in the above: `t.name` and `= "LocationTag"`.